# How to store data that would require 1024 columns in a django model (relational db)?

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-design

I have a django app that will need to read/write data into a table (table doesn't exist yet).

The data to be read/written consists of a 1024 vector of floats. It's really a 32x32 grayscale image rolled into a vector. (The vector represents a single entry)

In this case, I'm assuming I need a table with 1024 +id columns. Is this the best practice for this type of situation?

How to do that in django with the models? Will I need to create a class with 1024 atributes like this?

```
class ImageData(models.Model):
    pixel_1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=16)
    pixel_2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=16)
    ...
    pixel_1024 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=16)
```

Comment: Why not use an `ImageField`?

Comment: or `ArrayField`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem To my understanding, ImageField would save everything as an image file, and I really just need the vectors floats. At no point I'm going to need the files. Besides I will need to read them all at once for ML training, which seems like a poor perfomance choice (might be wrong about this) to read every file, turn them in a matrix and append to a dataframe. Although, it's probably better than creating 1024 columns.

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan it does seems like a better choice to me, however it looks like to be exclusive to postgres. Is there anything similar in the generic models? Thanks.

Comment: As I know, no. But mysql also has ListField, not sure what db you are going to use. There are some third party packages and you can also create your own Field classes.